# undetected chromedriver use Profile cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:58726

Tags: python, google-chrome, driver

**i try to use undetected_chromedriver but and use profile**

> this is my code
>
> the browser and profile is open but the driver is not working
>
> i need my profile run using chromedriver.exe

```
import time

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common import by
from selenium.webdriver.common.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\moh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
    chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 6')
    driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path="chromedriver.exe", use_subprocess=True, options=chrome_options)
url = ""
driver.get(url)
```

> i have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/moh/PycharmProjects/jjjkuh/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path="chromedriver.exe", use_subprocess=True, options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 401, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 589, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\moh\PycharmProjects\jjjkuh\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:58726
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it was okay after deleting Profile/Perferences file in profile directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I wonder where is the location of `Profile/Perferences`?